# Admob Interstitial Ads on Multiple Button Click

Tags: android, admob

I have an activity with 10 buttons, each one goes to a different activity. When I added the interstitial ads on button click, it works fine, but when the user closes the ad, it always takes him to activity (topic_ten). No matter what button he clicks, it always takes him to activity (topic_ten).

What I want is, when the user clicks the button for activity (topic_one), it takes him to activity (topic_one) and so on.

```
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_topics_list);

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1164579427694627/2090370128");
    interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());



    bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()){

                interstitialAd.show();
            }

            else {

                startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_one.class));

            }
        }
    });
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_two.class));
            interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
    bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()){

                interstitialAd.show();
            }

            else {

                startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_two.class));

            }
        }
    });
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_three.class));
            interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does `interstitialAd...listener....` need to be encapsulated in the block above ?

Comment: i am using android studio

Comment: I have no idea whether it needs to be encapsulated or not.

Answer (score 1):

try this method.

```
interstitialAd1 = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitialAd1.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1164579427694627/2090370128");
interstitialAd1.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

interstitialAd2 = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitialAd2.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1164579427694627/2090370128");
interstitialAd2.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {

        if (interstitialAd1.isLoaded())
            {

                interstitialAd1.show();
            }

        else 
            {

                startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_one.class));

            }
        }
    });

interstitialAd1.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        interstitialAd1.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_one.class));

    }

});


bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (interstitialAd2.isLoaded()){

            interstitialAd2.show();
        }

        else {

            startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_two.class));

        }
    }
});
interstitialAd2.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        interstitialAd2.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        startActivity(new Intent(topics_list.this, topic_two.class));

    }

});
```

I have just created two interstitial with same ad unit id.  Use it with setonclicklistener and  adlistener to control the flow when ads are closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enum method to handle multiple clicks to load different activity on clicks. And you just have to implement only one interstitial add. You have to declare list of enum to identify each activity.

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;    
ActivityType activityType;
public enum ActivityType {
    DRINKLOG, DRINKREPORT,WEIGHTREPORT
}
```

When you implement click listener for buttons you have to just check if add is loaded or not.

```
fabDrink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                activityType = ActivityType.DRINKLOG;
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                Timber.e("Loading" + "second");
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

To initialize interstitial add make a method which has its key , and listeners.

```
mInterstitialAd = newInterstitial();
private InterstitialAd newInterstitial() {
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_id));
    interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            mInterstitialAd = newInterstitial();
            switch (activityType) {
                case DRINKLOG:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case DRINKREPORT:
                    Intent activity2= new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(activity2);
                    break;

                case WEIGHTREPORT:
                    Intent activity3= new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity3.class);
                    startActivity(activity3);
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
    return interstitialAd;
}
```